# Use or convert .ttf font for console use in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, fonts, ttf

I have a monospace .ttf font I really like (UbuntuBeta Mono). Is there any way I can use it (or convert first and then use, if needed) for the console in freeBSD?
I know there is `usr/share/syscons/fonts`, but it looks like they might be a different format? Once I install the font, how do I tell the console to use it?

Answer (score 6):

It would depend upon the font formats that FreeBSD accepts in `usr/share/syscons/fonts`.

You can use [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) to convert a TTF font into other formats. According to this [blog post](http://www.freebsddiary.org/console-fonts.php), FreeBSD accepts the Slackware `.fnt.gz` format (the .gz just indicates it is zipped).

The Linux console uses `.psf.gz` fonts. You might try one of those to see if it works, if so you could use [PSF Tools](http://www.seasip.info/Unix/PSF/index.html) to do the final conversion to that format.

If all that goes to plan, you can tell the console to use it with the `vidcontrol` command and then, if you wish to make it permanent, add it to your `rc.conf`. The blog post linked to above has the details.