# How do I use a font in .ttc format as the console font?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, tty, ttf

I rather dislike the available `tty` fonts and would rather use Menlo, which is what I use in OS X's Terminal. Menlo is in a `.ttc` format, but (from the contents of `/usr/share/consolefonts`) Linux seems to require `.psf.gz` fonts, with different files for each combination of style and size. How do I convert it to the proper format and set it to be used as the font in `tty`s?

(I have a PowerBook G4 running Ubuntu Server 12.04 and an Intel MacBook Pro running OS X Mountain Lion.)

Comment: TTC is a container format containing more than one font file. See here how to convert TTF to PSF: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/use-or-convert-ttf-font-for-console-use-in-freebsd

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to worry about "decomposing" a TTC font in various separate fonts, as `fontconfig` knows how to read such files.

In other words, you can simply create a subdirectory named `~/.fonts` (that is, `.fonts` inside your home directory) and copy your font file there. It will be picked up by `fontconfig` and you will be able to use it just fine, *provided* that your terminal emulator knows how to use xft.

Since you mention Debian, the packages `gnome-terminal`, `rxvt-unicode` (all variants, except `lite`), and others would support such a font. See, for example:

[image: System using DejaVu with terminal using Menlo, from a TTC (see the left window)]

## Addendum

Since you mention using Debian (part 2), you may want to inspire yourself in the [package](https://salsa.debian.org/fonts-team/fonts-anonymous-pro/tree/master/debian) that I maintain of the font Anonymous Pro and create a personal package that you can use to deploy the font in your own systems.

I personally do that for fonts that I take from my MacOS X iBook and from Windows. (Of course, the packages are only for your own private use: you should *not* distribute them, unless you get a license from each font designer).

## For console-only ("text screen")

If you wish to create a font for the "text screen" only, then you may want to check the howto from [Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=770649#p770649).

Comment: Gah. Since this question was posted, I've switched to Ubuntu Server… XD Do you know if your answer will work under that?

Comment: @BlacklightShining, yes, it will, as the fundamentals are the same (and some packages even share the same maintainers).

Comment: Doesn't it need to be in a systemwide directory? Like `/etc/fonts`, maybe? (I did try making a `~/.fonts` and putting the exported `.ttc` file there, but it didn't show up in the list.)

Comment: @BlacklightShining, It only needs to be in a systemwide directory *if* you want it to be available for all users. By the way, you should *NOT* install a font under `/etc` as that directory is specifically meant for configuration files.

Comment: …I _do_ want it to be available for all users? (Does it even get changed to a user-specific font after you log in?) And no go on the `/etc/fonts`, got it. XD

Comment: Nice screenshot! Okay, this should work for terminal-emulating apps, but what about the `tty`s?

Comment: @BlacklightShining, I just added a picture for you to see the `.ttc` and the resulting use. For a font like this, the best-current-practice would be to package it and put it under `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`. If you choose not to create a package, then you can just put it under `/usr/local/share/fonts` and be done with it (but this is a solution that's not as clean).

Comment: Whoops, Stack Exchange doesn't like the size of the comment thread. Better [move it to a chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7677/discussion-between-blacklight-shining-and-rbrito)