# How do I use this .ttf file as my terminal font?

Tags: linux-mint, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use or convert .ttf font for console use in FreeBSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/use-or-convert-ttf-font-for-console-use-in-freebsd)
>   [Ubuntu Server, set terminal font to a custom ttf font?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32753/ubuntu-server-set-terminal-font-to-a-custom-ttf-font)

I'm using Linux Mint 13, with Cinnamon.  I have a .ttf file that I'm trying to use as my terminal font.  I figured the directory for terminal fonts is /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ so I copied my .ttf file there.  However, it doesn't show up in the terminal preferences font list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean terminal emulator rather than tty font right?

Comment: @warl0ck um...nope.

Comment: Console font is not a truetype one

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32753/ubuntu-server-set-terminal-font-to-a-custom-ttf-font

Comment: @KorganRivera I'm somewhat concerned you may have misunderstood warl0ck's question. So, with appologies in advance for a possibly stupid question... Is this terminal running inside a graphical session; is it in a window? Or is it the entire screen, there aren't even menu bars, launcher, etc.? Do you select "Terminal" from a menu or launcher to get to it? [Getting a truetype font to work in X11 is a *lot* less work than for the vga or framebuffer terminal]

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is probably there:
http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-mint-after-installation-mint-13-cinnamon-edition.htm#Install-Extra-Fonts

So to make it available, you may only have to run `fc-cache -f -v` with root rights.